# What options do I have for NG4 library boiler plate generators?

Tags: angular

I understand that the ng-cli currently does not have any feature that can be used for building standalone module libraries.
Does anyone have any tools they can recommend? I would prefer something that is compatible with webpack and supports .scss out of the box.

Comment: The angular-cli has been updated, and it now uses webpack, and it's really easy to work with. It also has an option to give templates with sass (`--style=sass`)

Comment: I know that, but what it doesn't do is have an option to create a library. Libraries have no need for things like index.html and some of the other boilerplate that comes with a cli created project. Also it doesn't create the *.typings files, the *.d.ts files and the rest of the library specific boilerplate.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://blog.mgechev.com/2017/01/21/distributing-an-angular-library-aot-ngc-types/